# unable to connect to socket io server using python

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a data stream using socket io.

1. I have tried changing the socket io version. I dont know what exact version the server is using.
   how do I get the the right version required to connect to this server ?

All I get is an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9173c0d3bafc> in <module>
      4 sio = socketio.Client()
      5 
----> 6 sio.connect(socketEndpoint, transports = 'websocket')
      7 sio.emit('join', { 'channelName': 'B-BTC_USDT' })
      8 

c:\users\z00451nh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py in connect(self, url, headers, transports, namespaces, socketio_path)
    280         except engineio.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
    281             self._trigger_event(
--> 282                 'connect_error', '/',
    283                 exc.args[1] if len(exc.args) > 1 else exc.args[0])
    284             raise exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None

c:\users\z00451nh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ConnectionError: Connection error
```

I tried with

1. python-socketio 5.0.4 & python-engineio 4.0.0(Default install version by pip)
2. python-socketio 4.6 & python-engineio 3.14.2
   code:

```
import socketio

socketEndpoint = 'wss://stream.coindcx.com'
sio = socketio.Client()

sio.connect(socketEndpoint, transports = 'websocket')
sio.emit('join', { 'channelName': 'B-BTC_USDT' })

@sio.on('B-BTC_USDT')
def on_message(response):
    print(response.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like the server is down
checked here https://www.websocket.org/echo.html